# Using 'this' keyword with Retrolambda

Tags: android, lambda, retrolambda

I have a problem with this code:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
        getDefaultIntent();
    }
});
```

I want to convert this code to use a lambda expression like this:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(()->{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
    getDefaultIntent();
});
```

But it wont work because now `this` doesn't refer to the inner class.

Comment: you are correct.  It won't work.  `this` always refers to the surrounding scope, never the lambda itself

Comment: @iagreen is their a workaround to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3),

> The value denoted by `this` in a lambda body is the same as the value
>   denoted by `this` in the surrounding context.

As such, if you need to use `this` to refer to the anonymous object, you need to use an explicit anonymous object, not a lambda.  The work around is writing it like your original code.

Lambda's are a tool that are useful in lots of situations, but do not need to be used in *all* situations.

Answer (score 0):

try inform to parameter, the "complete address" of (this).

```
removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
```

Like these:

```
removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(MainActivity.this);
```

of course, that you need inform your real class name.

Comment: removeGlobalOnLayoutListener() 

takes ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener as an argument not an activity